# HeatMap on Timezone map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, heatmap

I have created a timezone map with the help of this link http://techslides.com/time-zone-world-map-with-d3-and-topojson .This is what I have showing up -
[image]
Now I need to overlay a heatmap on this with data from another json file which looks like this -

```
{
"tz":
     [-12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],    

"data": 
     [2, 3, 32, 0, 7287, 20615, 3254, 23793, 36104, 411......]
}
```

I now need to change the colors on the Timezone map depending on the data values, shading the map with a light color for timezones with lower data value and a darker shade for higher data values. I am not quite sure how to go about with this. Any ideas will be highly appreciated.Thank you !!